# Failing to create an IIS 7.5 worker process memory dump

Tags: iis, iis-7.5

Using DebugDiag 1.2, I can create a memory dump though Tools -> IIS/COM+ services, and get a memory dump of all the worker processes BUT 1. It is the one I am having issues with (6GB of private memory used).

Any ideas???

Comment: The error I get is:
Could not create dump file D:\blabla.dmp for process ID 66123. GetLastError returns 0x80070057